# Android Market - Advertising a paid application within a free application: How to get the currency your user will pay in?

Tags: android

I have a free Android application which I have recently made a paid version of. Within the free application I would like to advertise the paid application to encourage current users to purchase it.

Doing that in itself is not difficult, but the problem comes in when displaying the price of the application. My app caters to an international audience, and as such I would like to show the price in the users currency.

I've done a fair amount of research, and came across [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails), which can be used to automatically convert the price of your in-app purchases, but I'm unsure if there's a way I can use that to do the same for my purposes.

I've also looked into creating in house interstitial ads with AdMob, as I think that would do the conversion for me. I am somewhat confused though, as I only appear to be able to make interstitial ads for in-app purchases, which my application does not contain.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is automatically done when you request the price from the In-App-Billing library. 
If you use the `price` field of the SKU details, it will include the price and the currency as well (see `getSkuDetails() in the [Billing reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)).
The currency is always the currency of the Google user which is logged in on Google Play.

Comment: But can I request the price of a separate paid application on the store from my free application? It is not an In-App purchase.

Comment: Oh that way. No I don't think you are able to. AdMob has such service (cross promotion), here's an info page about it: https://www.google.com/admob/promote.html 
Worst case what you can do is display the hardcoded price for the top 10 countries where your app is used, and hide the price on other countries. Or don't display the price at all.